# Запятые перед «как»

Tags: запятые, как

1. Известен своими работами() как актер и композитор.
2. Он ведет себя(,) как один из героев «Гарри Поттера».

Добрый день.

Старая добрая запятая перед «как». Почему в первом случае ее нет, а во втором – есть? И есть ли какая-нибудь суперкраткая памятка-шпаргалка, чтобы не лезть каждый раз на грамоту.ру и т. д.? Именно запятая перед «как» уже давно сидит занозой, хочу как-нибудь окончательно с ней расправиться.

Спасибо = )

Comment: «Грамоту.ру» не склоняется.

Comment: Во втором тоже не надо запятую (нельзя изъять оборот).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы – **принцип крайнего даунизма лингвистов.** Он заключается в следующем: Если мы не имеем каких-то отчётливых инструкций по каким-то синтаксическим ситуациям, то мы можем просто написать их сами, но так, чтобы они не противоречили отчётливым официальным пунктам, в таком случае никто не сможет сказать, что мы ошиблись, если мы будем писать по таким правилам.  Пунктуация – как дерьмо на ботинке: люди просто хотят от него избавиться. Никому не нужны какие-то неопределённости, сложности, колебания и т. д, пунктуация не должна быть сложнее пальца. Вот именно такое правило для пунктуации при сравнительном обороте:

**0. Сравнительный оборот всегда обособляется, кроме 4 ситуаций:**

**1. Сравнительный оборот является сказуемым или входит в состав сказуемого.**

Вот примеры про случаи, когда оборот является сказуемым:

> Ты мне будто песня.
> Мы с ней словно родные сестры.
> Ручей по весне что река.
> Глаза у нее будто озера.

Входит в состав сказуемого в тех случаях, когда глагол, к которому относится оборот, является глаголом такого типа, как глаголы: вести себя, относиться, поступить (в значении сделать что-то), стать. То есть просто проверьте, сохраняет ли предложение смысл, если убрать сравнительный оборот, но подразумевать у глагола то же значение (у глагола ‟поступить” есть ещё значение поступить в университет, так что он будет сохранять смысл – он поступил). Она стала как бабочка (предложение ‟Она стала” – бессмысленное), он вёл себя как подобает (предложение ‟Он вёл себя” – бессмысленное).

**2. Сравнительный оборот является устойчивым сочетанием.**

> Он был силен как лев.
> Что пристал словно банный лист?

**3. Перед сравнительным оборотом стоит частица или союз.**

> Он дрался и как лев, и как гепард. (Союз перед сравнительным оборотом.)
> Я воспитал в себе это чувство праздника не как отдыха и просто средства для дальнейшей борьбы, а как желанной цели.
> Дети иногда рассуждают совсем как взрослые.
> Было светло почти как днём.
> Волосы у девочки вьются точь-в-точь как у матери.

**4. Пункт про в качестве оборот.**
Тут нужно подумать, как этот пункт сформулировать, также следует найти много примеров. В качестве оборот  может обособляться и не обособляться. Пока нет качественной формулировки, пусть лучше вы увидите, о чём речь, демонстративно, то есть по примерам. Надеюсь, что вы поймёте, о чём идёт речь.

> Следует признать, что, как пособие для студентов, рецензируемая книга имеет ряд существенных недостатков.
> Рецензируемую книгу можно рекомендовать как пособие для студентов.
>
> На Юрия Гагарина, как на первого человека в космосе, было возложено много обязанностей.
> Юрий Гагарин вошёл в историю как первый в мире космонавт.
>
> Он был известен как осторожный человек.
> Леонтьев увлёкся этой мыслью, но, как человек осторожный, пока что о ней никому не рассказывал.

Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу, в первом предложении нет запятой по пункту 4 и тому варианту, где нет обособления, а во втором предложении нет обособления по пункту 1.

Если вы будете писать по этому правилу, то никто не сможет уличить вас в ошибке. Помимо этих пунктов есть пункт про образ действия, но он нигде отчётливо не сформулирован, поэтому вы можете спокойно его игнорировать.

Если лингвисты хотят, чтобы это правило было сложнее, то пусть они напишут качественную статью хотя бы, а не ссылаются на быдланство Розенталя, написанное по этому вопросу.

Comment: У вас классное чувство юмора.

Comment: Добавить в первый пункт "или входит в него" и примеры. И во втором примере не должно быть запятой по нему.

Comment: А Розенталя не обзывать! Что бы вы знали без него? Нет никого лучше, а лучшее так злостно критиковать не надо.

Comment: + экзотические случаи, например: *Он сражался то как лев, то как скорпион.*

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. То, что мне было нужно! Да еще и подтвердилась мысль, что в этой сфере много «неоднозначностей», а значит можно смело применять ваш принцип крайнего даунизма.

P. S. А то редакторы по работе (я переводчик) зателепали вычерпывать откуда-то со дна странные доводы в пользу моих ошибок, от которых я уже просто боюсь обороняться.

Comment: @oleedd, лень обсуждать и что-то дополнять.

Comment: Надо бороться со своей ленью.

Comment: @alex_smither, `@JimKorbett` Ну так на Грамоте же есть чёткая и короткая инструкция: http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Comment: @oleedd Нельзя обзывать Розенталя?  Думаете, эти увещевания помогут? Ничуть, здесь нужно что-то более убедительное, чем слова.  Дайти альтернативный ответ. В Нацкорпусе достаточно подобных примеров с обособлением, а русская пунктуация, по мнению Розенталя, вариативна. Что ж, все писатели неграмотные? Розенталь дал в правилах частотный варианТ, но эта конструкция не так проста, вариативности у нее достаточно.  Мне прийти и дать ответ? А что же вы все не можете защитить Розенталя.? Хотя бы кто-нибудь выразил свое мнение, неужели все согласны с принятым ответом?

Comment: @oleed Прошел тест по указанной ссылке – остался вопрос:
«Кричит, как орел: стой, стрелять буду!» – грамота.ру считает, что здесь должна стоять запятая, но разве в данном случае нельзя сказать «по-орлиному», «орлом»?

Comment: @Sharon Хаять лучшее нелогично. У нас есть принцип: если изъятие оборота нарушает смысл, то оборот входит в сказуемое и запятую не ставим. Jim Korbett это упустил.

Comment: @oleed Принцип изъятия - это для младших школьников, а вы уже взрослый мальчик.  Почитайте грамматику (труды настоящих лингвистов, а не мифических), и вы узнаете много интересного. Сравнительный оборот - это особая конструкция (трехчастная, трехмерная), его в общую двухмерную плоскость  не уложишь. Фактически это свернутое СПП с придаточным сравнительным, а уж там-то запятая обязательно присутствует.  И мы имеем возможность включать оборот в структуру простого предложения или в предложение, аналогичное сложному.  Ну нельзя все так упрощать и искать единый принцип, как вы, всё это утопия.

Comment: @Sharon *Принцип изъятия - это для младших школьников* — протестую, другого нет.

Comment: @alex_smither Можно, но сравнение лучше. Всё-таки это правило родилось из-за примеров, в которых оборот между подлежащим и сказуемым или перед сказуемым, например: *Как орёл кричит, как мышь пищит.* В таких примерах только один вариант подходит. Лопатин же взял примеры, где оборот в конце (и только такие), а в таких подходят оба варианта. Теперь имеем кашу. Что надо знать: этот приём художественный, специфический, им лучше не увлекаться. Это больше как исключение. Эта статья на Грамоте нуждается в улучшении, там не всё гладко и не всё есть.

Comment: @oleed ПРИНЦИП, -а; м. [от лат. prīncipium - начало] 1. Основное, исходное положение какой-л. теории, учения, науки и т.п. Эстетические принципы. . Главные принципы механики. // Руководящее положение, основное правило, установка для какой-л. деятельности.  Я что-то не помню,  где у нас написано: Принцип изъятия  лежит в основе системы правописания для всех тем. Я знаю только три основных принципа пунктуации: семантический, грамматический и интонационный. А вы частный методический прием возводите в принцип. Мне вот такой принцип не нужен, и никакой другой тоже.

Comment: @Sharon Но он во многих темах фигурирует. Предложите что-то получше, но практическое, а не философию. Пока у нас есть только это.

Comment: @oleed  Это частный методический прием, позволяющий от сложного анализа перейти к простому формальному решению. Но иногда этот прием уводит нас от истины, то есть когда нужен именно настоящий анализ, а не формальный.

Comment: @Sharon Вообще-то возможность изъятия отображает грамматику. Это грамматический принцип (относится к таким). Когда уводит? Пример есть?

Comment: @oleed Три принципа обычно действуют сообща, разделять их не надо. А уводит как раз в нашем случае, когда существуют два грамматических решения, а вы своим принципом один из вариантов исключаете безо всяких оснований, предлагая формальный прием там, где ему не место. Да еще называете его принципом, чтобы уж никто не сомневался. Допустим, какое-то частное решение мы имеем в восьми случаях из десяти, можно ли тогда считать, что оно верно всегда? Вряд ли, а вы обобщаете и думаете, что можно, ничуть не сомневаясь в своей логике.

Comment: @Sharon Принцип — это маленькая инструкция (среди прочего), самое обычное значение (*Можно действовать по такому принципу*). Нет двух грамматических решений, оборот входит в сказуемое, и только так. Я против запятой в "ведёт себя как", "выглядит как". Там даже "так" не звучит.

Comment: @Sharon *Три принципа обычно действуют сообща, разделять их не надо* — нет, когда в грамматике есть варианты, открывается дорога следующему принципу. Они не идут наравне, это там же и описывается. А вы ставите интонационный принцип превыше грамматического: хочу паузу и поставлю запятую, меня не волнует. Сообща не принципы действуют, а объекты принципов.

Comment: Для справок. Превыше всего я ставлю семантический принцип.  Интонационным анализом пользуюсь только в тех случаях, когда для одной грамматики существует два решения, вот тогда по интонации делается выбор. А остальных случаях я обхожусь грамматическими правилами.
Принципы действуют сообща, так как каждое написание выражает определенное значение (содержание) и имеет две соответствующие друг другу формы (грамматическую и интонационную). Но в частных случаях имеется расхождение (запятая при отсутствии паузы или интонационное тире, не связанное с грамматикой). На этом, пожалуй, закончим дискуссию.

Comment: P.S.  Ответ лучше всего начинать с анализа практики по Нацкорпусу. И если ваши принципы противоречат значительному количеству примеров, то меняйте принципы, а не говорите, что писатели неграмотные и только вы молодец.

Comment: Ваша шизодискуссия только делает мой ответ лучше. Писатели пишут как попало, потому что нет нормального учебника. Как ещё они должны писать по этой теме, если в том же справочнике Розенталя половина темы – это по-быдлански организованный бред.

Comment: @Sharon Не вам их расставлять, они уже давно расставлены учёными. На первом месте грамматический, и это справедливо. Да блин, не принципы действуют, а люди действуют — по принципам. Мы пока действуем по правилам, а не по Нацкорпусу. Если в правилах ответа нет, мы обращаемся к Нацкорпусу.

Comment: Да, ребята, весело тут у вас.  Но ... неладно что-то в датском королевстве, с моей точки зрения, раньше форум был другим.  oleedd, так, говорите, смысл неважен, форма главнее содержания? И практика письма мало что значит? Но ведь язык развивается, совершенствуется, подбирает новые формы, а правила более полувека назад были написаны. Вот Валгина, к примеру, с уважением относилась к практике. Хотя вряд ли что можно изменить,  но чуть позже я все-таки дам свой ответ, в принципе он простой и короткий. Так сказать, для завершения нашей шизодискуссии.

Comment: @Sharon От себя ничего не говорю, это не моё, это вам к РАН, вы же рядом. Не мало что значит, но правила превыше. А когда они устареют, издадут новые.

Comment: @JimKorbett Непонятное — это не бред, бред — неправильное. Мне вот понятно. Не называйте всё, что не понимаете, бредом, это тупо. Задавайте вопросы о том, что вам не понятно... Да, он маловато написал. Можно предположить, что у него не было больше информации. Он говорил, что использовал источники...

Comment: "Силён, как лев" не очень устойчивое, запятую обычно ставят.

Comment: Пример из справочника Розенталя.

Comment: Где? Искал там и не нашёл.

Comment: Где-то есть. Я бы тоже не считал бы его устойчивым сочетанием и ставил бы запятую.

Comment: Не могу найти, перерыл всё... Гугл находит только ваш ответ.

Comment: Примеры в моём конспекте из справочника Розенталя. Искать я ничего не буду.

Comment: Нет такого (проверил ещё раз), вы что-то перепутали!

Comment: Может да, может может нет, а может...

Answer (score 3):

**В КАЧЕСТВЕ ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ**

**1. Сравнительный оборот (СО) — особая конструкция**

Материал дан по учебному пособию для филологических  факультетов:  А. Ф. Прияткина. Синтаксис осложненного предложения, 2016.

**Почему особая?**  Классическая структура  СО — **это трехчастная форма** (два предмета (сущ. в И.п.) сравниваются между собой через действие (глагол) или предикативный признак (в именном сказуемом).
Между предметами **сочинительный вид связи,** а между глаголом и предметами — **подчинительная связь**. СО обозначает предмет или лицо, например: *Ее уста, как розы, рдеют.*

Такая структура дает возможность **подчеркнуть или сочинительную, или подчинительную связь** —  так задается вариативность для СО. Обычно он обособляется (выделена сочинительная связь), но может и не обособляться (выделена подчинительная связь).

**2. О глагольном сочетании «вести себя»**

Считается, что для него характерна семантическая невыраженность, но ему просто в обязательном порядке **требуется обстоятельство.** Для сравнения: такая же невыраженность  **у переходных глаголов**, требующих прямого дополнения.  СО используется в качестве такого обстоятельства и обычно не обособляется, но в частных случаях обособление возможно.

**3. Как грамматика СО может быть связана с семантикой**

Если СО обособлен, то ударение падает на глагол, и тогда подчинительная связь (обстоятельственное значение) уходит на второй план.  А если не обособлен, то глагол находится в безударной позиции (ударение падает на СО,  подчеркивается обстоятельственное значение СО).
При чем тут семантика? Постановка ударения зависит от конкретной ситуации общения для данного предложения и определяется заданным смыслом.

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

1. ***Известен своими работами как актер и композитор.***

В этом предложении нет сравнительных отношений — оборот имеет значение тождества (приравнивания, отождествления). Это пункт 4(2) в правилах Розенталя.

2. ***Он ведЕт себя, как один из героев «Гарри Поттера».***

Здесь обособление оборота во многом определяется **структурой предложения** (СО значительно распространен).  Распространенность конструкций всегда увеличивает вероятность обособления, иначе простое предложение трудно прочитать в одну фразу.

Потому интересно рассмотреть решение для нераспространенного оборота:
***Он ведет себя(,) как Гарри Поттер.***

Тогда оба варианта возможны, а обособление зависит **от смысла ситуации**:
*Он ведет себя / как Гарри ПОттер.  Он ведЕт себя, // как Гарри ПОттер.*
В первом предложении глагол находится в безударной позиции, а во втором предложении  на него падает ударение.

3. **В Нацкорпусе** оборот не обособляется в девяти случаях из десяти, но исключения все-таки встречаются, причем  **они не единичны:**

В этом смысле потребитель **ведет себя,** как стажеры доктора Хауза: пытаются диагностировать экзотическую лихорадку там, где налицо очевидное ОРЗ.
Жаловалась на мужа, что он в детстве один был у мамы в семье и вот теперь **ведет себя,** как избалованный ребенок ― придирается, орет, просит прощения, закатывает истерики.
Старый писатель, которому режиссер предназначил клоунскую роль, ― но и сам-то забавляющийся главреж **ведет себя,** как верховный паяц страны.
Отменять тендер, не отменять, Владимир Ефимович **ведет себя,** как глупый лис, который залез в курятник.
А та ведь здорова, по сути, совершенно здорова, но **ведет себя,** как законченная эгоистка.
И время **ведет себя,** как тупая игла на заезженной пластинке, ― срывается на повтор, да, Лева, нет?
Похвальная любовь к классике, но, между прочим, русская классическая литература проповедует гуманизм и любовь к ближнему, а она **ведет себя,** как свинья!

4. Попробуем представить **ситуации с разной постановкой ударения.**

(1)  *Он как-то странно себя ведёт. — Я тоже заметил: он ведет себя как Гарри Поттер.*  Тема поведения была уже задана, поэтому ударением подчеркивается только оборот.

(2) *Он чем-то похож на Гарри Поттера.  —  А чем именно? — Он ведЕт себя, как Гарри Поттер.* Тема поведения только появляется и потому подчеркнута ударной позицией глагола.

5. **У Розенталя** эта тема вполне понятно изложена в п. 4(1) и 4(4).

**Пункт 4.** Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми:

(1) если на первый план выступает значение **обстоятельства** образа действия;

(4) если сравнительный оборот **входит в сказуемое** (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота). Здесь праведен пример: ***В баснях звери / ведут себя как люди.***

Мне же представляется, что задачу надо решать по п. 4(1). Это частотный вариант без  обособления, когда на глагол невозможно поставить ударение, что определяется структурой предложения.

6. Итак, **оборот обособляется,** если возможен вариант с ударной позицией глагола и это требуется автору для выражения определённого смысла. Таким образом,  мы наглядно видим,  как **три принципа пунктуации** соответствуют друг другу и составляют единое целое.

**О РОЗЕНТАЛЕ**

Это был удивительный человек, и его заслуги перед обществом трудно переоценить: **вот уже полвека вся страна изучает правописание по Розенталю.**  При этом он был очень скромным человеком и не очень высоко оценивал свой вклад в создание правил русского письма. А ведь фактически он «расшифровал» тезисные правила 1956 года и сделал их пригодными для использования в учебном процессе.

**Но мы удивительно неблагодарны и вечно недовольны его редакцией**: лучше надо было написать, понятнее. Но это уже задача для нового Розенталя, который найдется не так скоро. Еще бы! Такой огромный труд,  а ученую степень за него не получишь — ведь это практика, а не чистая наука. К тому же общество  еще **не готово к восприятию новых идей**, к использованию современной грамматики. И нужен нам уже не справочник, а учебник, где материал будет систематизирован.

Интересно существуют ли где-нибудь памятник Розенталю?  Я думаю, что вряд ли. Что ж, он, как и Пушкин, «**памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный».**

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Цитата из статьи** «Ударные правила Розенталя» (philologist — ЖЖ (livejournal.com).

*Можно без преувеличения сказать, что все люди литературного труда в позднем СССР выросли на учебниках Розенталя. Преподаватели, журналисты, писатели, драматурги – все знали это имя от своих школьных учителей или университетских профессоров. Он не считал, разумеется, что придумал правила русского языка – сам себя называл черновым рабочим. Дескать, просто отыскал источники, систематизировал полученные знания и изложил их в виде справочников.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143123/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Надеюсь, вы прочитали последние комментарии. Для вас старался.

Comment: Эта статья — это пересказ интервью, странный формат.

Comment: *Он написал 150 учебников, не считая научных статей* — где это всё?! В интернете наименований 10 (не считая переиздания). Может, это фейк, кочующий из одной статьи в другую?

Comment: На мой взгляд, он был недоумком, который обладал удивительным даром превращать максимально простые вещи в невозможные для понимания.

Comment: Уважаемые друзья, ваши комментарии приходится читать мне, а мне это неинтересно. Вы не могли бы перебраться куда-нибудь еще...

Comment: Так они обновляются, может, вам в чат пойти или пишите под своими ответами..

Comment: Надо модератору пожаловаться... это моя территория.

Comment: @oleedd Я вам не джинн из бутылки, чтобы "тоже" ваши команды выполнять. https://azbyka.ru/fiction/volshebnoe-slovo-valentina-oseeva/

Comment: @Sharon Это не услуга для меня, поэтому будьте попроще. Ваши комментарии остались висеть, в них нет смысла, теперь это просто мусор. Здесь все сообща удаляют, кроме вас.

Comment: @oleedd А вы в другой  раз не будете рядом со мной размещаться, ага? А то расположились, как туристы у чужой дачи. Костерчик развели, громкую музыку включили.

Comment: @Sharon Я подключился и был третьим (вы не в счёт). Хотел защитить Розенталя, как обычно. Что в этом плохого?